# Visual Basic - Download zip, extract, and put it somewhere?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am a bit new to VB - So hopefully you can help me.

I have a server, in which people use a browser I made, to upload files for others to download. I am making a system in which a user will update their files - other users will automatically download the new files and put them in a special place replacing other files.

I have looked this up, and I don't seem to find straight answers in which will solve my problems. Should I do it via FTP, and have it download?

The files I wish for them to download need to be put in a specific folders inside %AppData%, How would I do that aswell?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. FTP should work well for that the file transfer. That's what I would probably use.
2. You can get the path for %AppData% using

> System.Windows.Forms.Application.UserAppDataPath

Comment: Thanks. But I've heard rumors people can view source code of vb.net programs. Cant they get my FTP info from it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the file yourself from an [ftp site using vb.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/77912-ftp-download-delete/). This is the best option for file transfer.

For you unzipping of the files take a look at the [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks. But I've heard rumors people can view source code of vb.net programs. Cant they get my FTP info from it?

Comment: @Alex - That is another question entirely and one which has been asked many times before - have a look at [this question about .NET obfuscation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation) to get you started